# My font looks blurry on book cover

Tags: fonts, book, posters

I am starting out as an author and do my own book covers using ‘Be Funky.’ I start out with a photo and edit it to suit, and then ‘add text.’ The problem is that my text sometimes looks blurry when seen on Amazon. AND when I print it off to use as a poster. Looks fine on my screen but seems to diffuse when uploaded. This is driving me nuts. Can anyone help please?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite sure you have recently seen the next writing and then it looked much sharper than now:

[image]

The difference: My copy is a screenshot. Letters are as big as in the original and contain as much screen pixels, but the original is sharp because the shown raster image on your screen is formed (=rendered) in your computer from exact vector font data and every letter is placed to fit optimally (=hinted) into the screen pixel raster.

My version do not at all respect pixel borders of your screen, all edge pixels are blurred because a part of every edge pixel should be black and the rest should be white.

So, do not expect an image of text look as sharp as text which is as tall, but rendered in watcher's computer. To make your texts look sharp you should have the image of text 2...4 times as tall as the locally rendered text which looks as sharp.

A PDF file is rendered locally in PDF reading programs, so even the small print can look sharp if it's not an image, but vector font data.

I'm afraid that marketplaces do not provide any method how you could force the text parts in your images to be rendered locally. You can only attach JPGs or PNGs.

There's another answer which reveal another important fact: Websites often compress the image i.e. make them need less storage space. Unfortunately it makes them more blurry.

Your best way to fight against the blurriness is to have important texts of images in bigger size and repeat them in web page text. If a person sees a sharp version at first he probably doesn't notice that the same text in an image is a little blurry - assuming, of course that the same text in the image is readable.

Make a little research. Find some good looking advertisement images of books or posters in the same marketplace that you are going to use. Download a few such images for analyzing. I mean download, do NOT grab a screenshot!!!!

Get a locally runnable photo editor or use some "free of nice looking tricks" image editing website such as Photopea. Even Widows Paint can be used.

Make your image to have the same pixel dimensions as the good looking one. Be sure that the texts in your image are as tall in pixels as texts in the good looking image.

For making prints which have sharp texts either have massive pixel dimensions or use local software which can handle and keep the text parts as vector font data. Inkscape for example is a free, but there are others.

ADD: You asked in a comment "back to the drawing board?" Yes. Marketplaces do not show your images as you expect. Either the images should be made to tolerate the marketplace (= no small texts which should stay sharp) or build your ad so that unsharp images of texts do not harm.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment. It's now an answer.  Yeah, these kind of websites are probably not set up for accepting PDFs.  Maybe a massive poster-sized PNG at 300dpi would work, but there may be limits on file size for uploading.

Comment: it's fixed now. High resolution image of text will not be shown sharp in small size due lack of hinting.

Comment: Thank you both for really great answers. Much appreciated.But I am a novice and am not sure how to begin. Would ‘flattening’ my layers photo plus text achieve a well defined result or am i back to the drawing board.

Comment: @AlfieB   Can you get something else out from Be Funky than a JPG or PNG? What other options you have? Maybe PSD? or PDF? or SVG or what?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if text looks fuzzy/pixelated on a raster image (ie. an image made of pixels), it means the image isn't high enough resolution. Images which look fine on-screen will probably not be high enough resolution for printing. You probably need to design your cover at a much larger size (larger in pixel dimensions). Sorry, I've no idea what is possible with the software or website you are using. It may not be suitable for print work.

Also uploading images to websites can degrade image quality if the website is automatically adding compression to the image or resizing the image, for example when converting to JPEG for inclusion on a website.

To print a poster sized image, something like an A1 size for example, then in terms of resolution 150dpi might be acceptable for a large format print like this.

A1 = 23.4 x 33.1 inches

@150dpi = 3510px x 4965px

When creating artwork for print however, it's best to use software which can output text as vectors. Software like Photoshop (not free) and GIMP (free) can do this when exporting as PDF.  If you try to rasterize text at 150dpi for example by exporting the design in a raster format such as PNG/JPEG etc, it will look blurry/pixelated when printed and inspected up close. You could perhaps compensate by using a higher resolution raster image, but that would make a much larger image size (with a larger file size).